# Best method to integrate newest version of codebase with current local changes

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

First off, apologies for being long-winded here... I am new to version control and have done some research but haven't found anything that seems to fit my current situation. I want to be sure that I'm making the right move going forward, so a million thanks in advance for any suggestions!

I purchased an application source code from Envato and have been customizing it locally. When I downloaded the project it was using an old version of Flutter and a lot of outdated dependencies.

On my current machine I've updated a lot of this, added/removed features, made considerable changes to the appearance and migrated the entire project to Android v2 embedding & Flutter v2.10

Now, here's the part where I'm banging my head... I did all this without creating a repository and this week the authors released an update which adds several features, improvements and also upgraded the project to Flutter v2.10!

My question is this: **How do I keep the changes I've made locally while updating to the newest release from the original authors?**

Today, I downloaded the updated project, initialized a private repository and created a new branch for further development so I can avoid this situation moving forward. The version that i have been working on locally is in another directory. I have read about git merge vs rebase and am still unclear on what's the right thing. I REALLY do not want to start over as it's quite a complex project.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Backup all of your code before you start on this!

Comment: definitely learned this lesson the hard way! appreciate the tip

Comment: "Best" tends to be subjective. Git itself is a suite of tools, which can be used to achieve various end results; while one person might use them one way, someone else might use them another way, and it tends to be hard to say that any one particular method is "best". The good news with Git is that once you create a repository and make commits in it, those commits last forever, or at least, as long as you can supply their hash IDs to Git software that has a copy of the repository that has the commits in it. :-)

Comment: If you think of Git as storing a series of snapshots (like tarballs or winzip archives or whatever), plus some metadata that glues the snapshots together, you have the right idea. The tools then let you look at the relationships between snapshots, using the metadata, which links newer snapshots back to older ones.

Answer (score 2):

So you have 3 versions:

- Envato origin  I will name it E1
- Envato update, this is E2
- Your version, this is Y1

You want to merge the E2 on Y1:

```
       E2
     /    \
   E1--Y1--Y2
```

I fear this will be a big challenge if the conflict is big during the merge.
You should create a repository with E1.

```
git init
download first version
git add -A && git commit -m "First version"
```

Then create a branch, delete all files from E1 put E2 source code and create a commit

```
git checkout -b E2
rm -rf *
download second version
git add -A && git commit -m "Second version"
```

After that create another branch with your code, create a commit.

```
git checkout -b Y1 E1
rm -rf *
copy your version files
git add -A && git commit -m "My version"
```

And try to merge E2 on your code.

```
git merge E2
```

you will get a bunch of conflict during the merge, up to you to check if fixing the conflict is better than start again from E2

Comment: I think the last checkout command should be a differently named branch, and then start with commit `E1`? Maybe something like `git checkout -b my-branch E1` ?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I knew this was going to be complicated but this is a lesson that will definitely stick with me. Somehow i thought maybe `git rebase` would be my savior here but i wanted to be sure before i made any more mistakes.

Comment: Good catch @TTT I miss it